# WP7 Deeplink to Marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7, deep-linking, marketplace

Does anyone know what code to use specifically to jump from within a Windows Phone 7 application to the application's listing in the Marketplace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the sample code for MarketplaceDetailTask here.

[How to: Use Launchers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769550%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)